# What is the most "standard" worthy database library for c++?

Tags: c++, database, api, standards

In my personal c++ studies, I've focused on projects that 1) Keep me engaged and 2) Help teach a standard principle.  I want to do a project with database access.  Which libraries do you think best stick with the c++ programming paradigm?

I understand that this question is open to interpretation, so please elaborate on your choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might consider using the [Database Template Library](http://dtemplatelib.sourceforge.net/).

It provides a clean, iterator-based interface to access collections of records, so you can use it with all of the Standard Library algorithms.  It also does a pretty good job of limiting the boilerplate you need to write to map database entities to user-defined types in your project.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a fan of OTL (http://otl.sourceforge.net/) which also provides a clean, STL-like interface.  It's worked for my needs and is simple to use.